# Combining three values from XML file select into one

Tags: sql-server

I'm having problem with loading data from .xml file into my SQL Server Database. To this day I've been doing this with this query:

```
 BEGIN 
    DECLARE @XML AS XML,@hDoc AS INT
    SELECT @XML = CONVERT(XML, BulkColumn) 
    FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'D:\order2.xml', SINGLE_BLOB) AS x;

    EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @hDoc OUTPUT, @XML

    INSERT  INTO [dbo].[Client]
    SELECT *
    FROM OPENXML(@hDoc, 'orderType/client')

    WITH
    (
         OrderId varchar(200) '../../../sn',
         Client_number varchar(200) 'client_number',
         FirstName varchar(200) 'firstname', 
         LastName varchar(200) 'lastname', 
         E-Mail varchar(200) 'email'   
    )

   EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @hDoc   

END
```

But now i want to select `client_number`, `firstname` and `lastname` into one column, so it looks something like that:

```
|     Client      |
| - - - - - - - - |
|  134 John Smith |
```

I really appreciate your help and I apologize for messy code, as it is my first question here, on stackoverflow.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have a system to try it now but probably you can use a `CTE` to extract the values from the XML and combine them in the main query, something like

```
WITH XMLVal AS (
  SELECT *
  FROM OPENXML(@hDoc, 'orderType/client')
  WITH (OrderId varchar(200) '../../../sn',
        Client_number varchar(200) 'client_number',
        FirstName varchar(200) 'firstname', 
        LastName varchar(200) 'lastname', 
        E-Mail varchar(200) 'email'   
  )
)
INSERT  INTO [dbo].[Client]
SELECT *, concat(Client_number, ' ', FirstName, ' ', LastName)
FROM   XMLVal
```

I'm not sure if SQLServer will like the second `WITH` inside the `CTE`'s one